# Get cached value from Excel 2003 spreadsheet using Python xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have an Excel 2003 spreadsheet with values and formulas.  Using Python 2.7, I need to read all the values from the spreadsheet, and none of the formulas.  If a cell has a formula, I need the cached value from the cell.  Using xlrd, how can I get the actual values from cells which contain formulas?  My current method of retrieving the values in each cell gives me incorrect values for any cell which contains a formula.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

By default, I think that's how it works, right.  I mean, you have to go out of your way to get the formulas, and just a simple read will get you the data, or calculated values, right.

Try this.

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)

Comment: The OP has an Excel 2003 spreadsheet (.xls); openpyxl works on .xlsx files.